# RoR - Foreign Keys created via associations and migrate or "by hand" (or scaffold)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, foreign-keys, associations, scaffolding

Just starting to learn Ruby on Rails. I'm using RoR 3. I have read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

But I want to make sure I understand completely.

When creating a new model (I'm doing via scaffold for now), should I specify foreign_key fields at that point, or does the association handle that completely? I believe that association is only at app level, not at the db level, correct?

So I think I must do:

```
rails generate scaffold post body:text title:string user_id:integer
```

So in summary, when creating a blog application, must I specify the user_id field in the post model, or does the user model's `has_many  :posts` take care of actually adding that to the db (mine is mysql) when I migrate?

And if the answer is that I should do them when I create the model in the first place (via scaffold or by hand), what happens when I decide later on that I want to add a foreign key, must I add that as an `execute` statement in a new migration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct.  You need to specify the foreign key when you create your scaffold/model/migration as you stated to get the DB to be correct, and the has_many takes cares of the model for you.

So for initial generation of a scaffold (or model), just do:

```
rails generate scaffold post body:text title:string user_id:integer
```

as you stated, and add the `has_many` for the model itself.

For additions later on, you would make up a new migration, something like (assuming you want to use generation, but you could write your own migration):

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:integer
```

With that, you can run a `rake db:migrate`, and then update your model with a `has_many` or whatever association you need.

Comment: thanks. I thought that was the case. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: +1 for including how to do subsequent generation after creating initial scaffold. I had to read through half the 'Agile Web Dev with Rails' book before realising this simple but crucial difference.